# Clone ImageSource to save time xamarin.forms for android

Tags: view, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a list view that has around 50 lines.

Each line is my own custom list view cell that consists of a text view and am image view at the end.

The image is always the same for all 50 lines.

The image is an svg txt resource file.

I have an external package to convert the svg text to ImageSource (Vapolia.xamsvg)

The problem is that it takes me a around 40 - 50 ms to convert the svg string to image source and i have to do it 50 times in order to create 50 image view for 50 lines inside a listview

Can i duplicate (clone) the ImageSource and save the conversion of the svg to imageSource ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a byte array which can be provided in `MemoryStream` constructor:

```
var byteArray = yourStream.ToArray();
yourStream?.Dispose();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return new MemoryStream(byteArray); });
}
```